# Xcode app turns gray when I try to run it on real device

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, device, ios-provisioning

I can't find an answer to this anywhere. My app runs perfectly on the simulator, but when I plug it into my iPhone 5s, it gives me a gray screen when it runs. I have iOS 8.4 and Xcode 6.4. All my provisioning is set up correctly and the little app icon appears on my device screen. I can't figure out why when I tap it, it brings up the launch screen and then the screen immediately turns gray. Could this be an issue with my device?

Screenshot of screen when I try to run on device:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lxgq0.jpg

Edit:
I figured out that the device runs the code thats in the main storyboard, but nothing else. I'm making a SpriteKit-based game and all of my code is in scenes, the only thing I have in the storyboard is an iAd. I can't figure out why the simulator runs my GameScene but the device only runs what is posted in the storyboard.

Comment: post code, screenshots, storyboard screenshots, device type, ios version ... anything?

Comment: I edited that in. I would post a screen shot but it says I need more reputation.

Comment: You say "I edited that in." but I don't see any of your code in your question. For the screenshot, you can upload elsewhere then paste the link. Anyway, what we're saying is: **give all the details you can** otherwise your question is just words and nobody can help.

Comment: why gray and not green, blue or some other color? Unfortunately the question as is very vague at best and doesn't help us to help you.

Comment: I don't think its an issue with my code because the app runs perfectly on the simulator. I was just wondering if getting this gray screen is a known issue that people have. I posted a screenshot of my device.

Comment: How does it look in the simulator? Can you post that?

Comment: Despite what you say I think it is an issue with your code.  It would only take you 2 minutes to create a quick test app using an Xcode standard app template (which just displays a label for example), if you run that on your phone and it isn't grey then that is proof the issue is your code. Incidentally, is your app using a web view?

Comment: I figured out that the device runs the code thats in the main storyboard, but nothing else. I'm making a SpriteKit-based game and all of my code is in scenes, the only thing I have in the storyboard is an iAd. I can't figure out why the simulator runs my GameScene but the device only runs what is posted in the storyboard.

Comment: Post your ViewController code that handles the SKScene.  Do you create and store a reference to it?